# Python -> C++ idiom: Storing lambda expressions in a map/container

Tags: c++, qt, boost, lambda, idioms

I'm learning C++ (via Qt4) leveraging my python/pyqt4 experience, and I cannot seem to grasp the proper idiom for storing lambda expressions into a container for use as callbacks.

I have a struct with a bunch of fields. And I want to create a map of callbacks that can properly format the fields a specific way.

Here is the python equivalent of what I want to do:

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant, QString

class AType(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "FOO"
        self.attr2 = "BAR"
        self.attr3 = "BAZ"
        # ...

callbacks = {}
callbacks['name'] = lambda x: QVariant(QString(x.name))
callbacks['attr2'] = lambda x: QVariant(QString(x.attr2))
callbacks['attr3'] = lambda x: QVariant(QString(x.attr3))    

a = AType()
variant = callbacks['name'](a)

print variant.toString()
# PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'FOO')
```

At first I found native lambdas in C++ and started trying it out, but then found that it is apparently a C++11 feature. **Edit:** I want to know if there is a pre C++11 approach before I start investigating whether I can introduce the flag into the build system for the project.

Then I looked at boost solutions. My project is already using boost, so I thought it might be a solution. I see there are both [`lambda`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/lambda.html) and [`Phoenix`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/index.html) options. To show that I have at least tried to make this work, here is my embarrassing failure:

```c++
## my_class.h ##

#include <QVariant>
#include <QMap>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

QMap< uint, boost::function<QVariant (AType&)> > callbacks;

## my_class.cpp ##

#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include "my_class.h"

// I invite you to laugh at this 
callbacks[0] = boost::bind(&QVariant, boost::bind(&QString::fromStdString, boost::bind(&AType::name, _1)));
```

After I wrote that last line, I realized I am spinning my wheels and better just ask more experience C++ developers about the idiomatic approach to creating a map of lambda callbacks (compatable with Qt).

My goal is to be able to take a known index and a known `AType` instance, and be able to return a proper format `QVariant`

### Update

This is the solution I found to work, based on the accepted answer. Using C++98 compatible solution.

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

struct AType {
    AType();
    std::string name, attr2, attr3;
};

AType::AType() {
    name = "FOO";
    attr2 = "BAR";
    attr3 = "BAZ";
}

typedef QMap< QString, QVariant (*)( AType const& ) > Callbacks;

struct ATypeFieldMapper
{
    static QVariant name( AType const& x )
    { return QVariant(QString::fromStdString(x.name)); }

    static QVariant attr2( AType const& x )
    { return QVariant(QString::fromStdString(x.attr2)); }

    static QVariant attr3( AType const& x )
    { return QVariant(QString::fromStdString(x.attr3)); }
};


int main()
{
    Callbacks callbacks;
    callbacks["name"] = &ATypeFieldMapper::name;
    callbacks["attr2"] = &ATypeFieldMapper::attr2;
    callbacks["attr3"] = &ATypeFieldMapper::attr3;

    AType a;

    qDebug() << callbacks["name"](a).toString();
    qDebug() << callbacks["attr2"](a).toString();
    qDebug() << callbacks["attr3"](a).toString();

}

//"FOO" 
//"BAR" 
//"BAZ"
```

Comment: In C++11, use `std::map<K, std::function<R(A1, A2, ...)>>`.

Comment: Thanks but as I stated, I don't think I can use C++11 with Qt4. Can I?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: It's not that I **cant**. It is that I am working on part of a larger project and don't want to introduce anything different to the build system yet. I was just trying to figure out the non-C++11 approach if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ a lambda is nothing but syntactic sugar, that allows you to write functor definitions inline. A *functor* is an object with an `operator()`. So if you can't use C++11 (one reason might be because you're forced to use an old compiler?) then you can always just define functor classes, or if those conceptual lambdas don't capture anything, then you can just use *plain old functions*.

:-)

Kay, I'm going to write up an example. Just a few minutes...

---

Here goes…

```
struct QString{ QString( wchar_t const* ){} };
struct QVariant { QVariant( QString const& ) {} };
struct AType{ wchar_t const* name() const { return L""; } };

#include <functional>       // std::function
#include <map>              // std::map
#include <string>           // std::wstring
using namespace std;

void cpp11()
{
    typedef map< wstring, function< QVariant( AType const& ) > > Callbacks;
    Callbacks callbacks;
    callbacks[L"name"] = []( AType const& x )
        { return QVariant( QString( x.name() ) ); };

    auto const a = AType();
    auto variant = callbacks[L"name"]( a );
}

void cpp03Limited()
{
    typedef map< wstring, QVariant (*)( AType const& ) > Callbacks;
    Callbacks callbacks;

    struct SimpleConversion
    {
        static QVariant convert( AType const& x )
        { return QVariant( QString( x.name() ) ); }
    };

    callbacks[L"name"] = &SimpleConversion::convert;

    AType const a = AType();
    QVariant const variant = callbacks[L"name"]( a );
}

void cpp03General()
{
    struct IConversion
    {
        virtual QVariant convert( AType const& ) const = 0;
    };

    struct ConversionInvoker
    {
        IConversion const*  pConverter;

        QVariant operator()( AType const& x ) const
        {
            return pConverter->convert( x );
        }

        explicit ConversionInvoker( IConversion const* const p = 0 )
            : pConverter( p )
        {}
    };

    typedef map< wstring, ConversionInvoker > Callbacks;
    Callbacks callbacks;

    struct SimpleConversion: IConversion
    {
        virtual QVariant convert( AType const& x ) const
        { return QVariant( QString( x.name() ) ); }
    };
    SimpleConversion const simpleConversionFunc;

    callbacks[L"name"] = ConversionInvoker( &simpleConversionFunc );

    AType const a = AType();
    QVariant const variant = callbacks[L"name"]( a );
}

int main()
{}
```

Disclaimer: untested code (except that it compiles with msvc and mingw g++).

Comment: They capture the `AType` instance being passed, to return a formatted version of a specific field. I know I could just type out explicit functions to do the conversions. Was just hoping there was either a boost or native way to do it while I am learning. I didn't want to ask the project group about C++11 until I knew it was the only efficient way.

Comment: I'm noting, "just a few minutes" turned into 30 minutes. Oh my. I'm getting ooooooooold…

Comment: Hmm. So it seems like unless I have, what, GCC 4.6+, installed, I would need to be using the "General" approach? My OSX 10.6.8 box has GCC4.2. `cpp03Limited` seems to compile file, while `cpp03General` gets an error: `main.cpp:60: error: template argument for ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair’ uses local type ‘cpp03General()::ConversionInvoker’`

Comment: I didn't understand how to fix that last one (still learning) but its fine because the `cpp03Limited` seems to work and isn't too complicated. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, I think I accepted too soon. Does `cpp03Limited ` imply that I have to define N number of static method in the `SimpleConversion` struct? i.e:  `getName`, `getFoo`, `getBar` static methods, for every field?

Comment: I don't know, because this part of the question is pretty unclear (to me). It may be case of XY question: having a real problem X, but asking about shortcomings of perceived solution Y. Maybe the real problem has a much simpler solution in C++?

Comment: My question is that my struct will have a larger number of fields, each with a different way to format them into a QVariant end result. My goal was to create lambdas for every field and store them in the map so I can reference a key and get the right value for the right field.

Comment: Also let me add, I am very honest about my experience in C++ thus far. Very experience in python, but simply learning C++ via Qt. If there is an simpler solution in C++, by all means I would love it. It just seemed to me that what I am after is a mapping of callbacks. Your C++11 example looks almost exactly like what I would want if it weren't dependent on most-recent compilers. I am not sure, given the limited experience I have with C++ compilers, what the implications are in requiring C++11 compatibility.